# How to call angular form builder value changes after initial load

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a form that syncs with a Firestore database. Now when somebody changes the value of the 'Nationality' field I want to trigger some further actions like so:

```
this.profileFormStageOne.get('nationality').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      if (val && val === 'Other') {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Your Nationality',
          inputs: [
            {
              name: 'nationality',
              placeholder: 'Your Nationality e.g. Brazilian',
            },
          ],
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Update Nationality',
              handler: data => {
                this.manualNationality = data.nationality;
                console.log(this.manualNationality);
              },
            },
          ],
        });
        alert.present();
      }
    });
```

However I am also using ngOnChanges() to patch values with the form like so:

```
  /**
   * Get initial form values
   * Needs to run from ngOnChanges because User in an input & is not ready in constructor
   */
  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.User) {
      const profile: Profile = this.User.profile;

      this.profileFormStageOne.patchValue({
        nationality: profile.nationality,
```

The problem is this is called on the inital rendering (during patch value) if the Nationality field is already set to 'other'.

Is there any alternative approaches or ways to trigger on select change?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to changes on nationality like so

```
     this
      .profileFormStageOne.controls['nationality'].valueChanges.subscribe(()=> {
   // your login
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

do this way, in Angular 6

first, create a getter

```
get nationality() {
       this.profileFormStageOne.get('nationality');
 }
```

now

```
 this.nationalityChange = this.nationality.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
            if (value === 'other') {
              // do your requirement
            }
            this.nationality.updateValueAndValidity();
        });
```

you must call a `pathValue()` method to set the default value in `ngAfterViewInit()` hooks

and don't forget to unsubscribe the observable

```
ngOnDestroy() {
        this.nationalityChange.unsubscribe();
    }
```